# Getting Geolocation coordinates using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, geolocation

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of my position using AngularJS and Geolocation.
This is the function in the controller in which I am assigning the values of the latitude and the longitude and printing them out to the browser console. The nearme() function is called,

```
  var mysrclat= 0; var mysrclong = 0;
  $scope.nearme = function($scope) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                mysrclat = position.coords.latitude; 
                mysrclong = position.coords.longitude;
        });
        console.log(mysrclat);
        console.log(mysrclong);
    }
}
```

The issue is that, the first time, the coordinates print as 0, 0. Then, after that it prints the correct values of the coordinates. Why is it printing 0, 0 as the coordinates the first time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is easy :) your console.log is located beyond collback borders,

```
function (position) {
  mysrclat = position.coords.latitude; 
  mysrclong = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log(mysrclat);
  console.log(mysrclong);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/glebv/axrw7g90/18/

Comment: Thanks.. What do I do if i need to utilize the values of mysrclat and mysrclong beyond the callback borders? like in my case, i need to use those values in another function..I've tried assigning it to $scope variable and using it in the other function does not work as well..any ideas?

Comment: You should bind them to scope or to implement it as a service,  it's much better. You can use https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation, I guess it's very suitable for your task or review code of the service. It's very simple and use it for your porpoises.